# Using RSA/ECB/OAEPPadding algo for encryption key not working in android

Tags: android

I m using RSA/ECB/OAEPPadding algo for encryption logic when i use RSA/ECB/OAEPPadding algo in encryption method below error gets thrown in android
Error:
Error:javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: error:04000072:RSA routines:OPENSSL_internal:DATA_TOO_LARGE_FOR_KEY_SIZE
javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: error:04000072:RSA routines:OPENSSL_internal:DATA_TOO_LARGE_FOR_KEY_SIZE.

Earlier to this i was using RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding algo where same code base was working fine, now same code base just changed to RSA/ECB/OAEPPadding algo getting above exception

I tried using below code :

```
Key key = ...;
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/OAEPPadding");
// To use SHA-256 the main digest and SHA-1 as the MGF1 digest
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, new OAEPParameterSpec("SHA-256", "MGF1", MGF1ParameterSpec.SHA1, PSource.PSpecified.DEFAULT));
// To use SHA-256 for both digests
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, new OAEPParameterSpec("SHA-256", "MGF1", MGF1ParameterSpec.SHA256, PSource.PSpecified.DEFAULT));
```

but i get below exception:
CryptoHelper: Error:javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: error:0400007e:RSA routines:OPENSSL_internal:KEY_SIZE_TOO_SMALL
javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: error:0400007e:RSA routines:OPENSSL_internal:KEY_SIZE_TOO_SMALL

I m stuck with this task , not able to proceed further

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/OAEPPadding");
// To use SHA-256 the main digest and SHA-1 as the MGF1 digest
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, new OAEPParameterSpec("SHA-256", "MGF1", MGF1ParameterSpec.SHA1, PSource.PSpecified.DEFAULT));
// To use SHA-256 for both digests

Use above code it is working fine